# Swift library package produces empty archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I'm trying to produce a `.xcframework` compiled version of my Swift library package. With an Xcode managed library target, I can archive the scheme and the resulting framework could be embedded and linked by another project. However, when I attempt to archive a pure swift package (that is to say, the dir containing the `Package.swift` file is what's open in Xcode, there is no `.xcodeproj`), the resultant archive is empty, devoid of any build products.

This is reproducible both in my project and also with a brand new Swift library package (obtained by running `swift package init --type library`). It's reproducible whether I archive through Xcode's gui or with `xcodebuild archive -scheme 'MyPackage' -destination "generic/platform=iOS" -archivePath archive.xcarchive BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES SKIP_INSTALL=NO`.

The latter produces a binary, but no module map or any of the resources included in the library. The former produces a completely empty archive.

Swift Package Manager supposedly supports the distribution of pre-compiled libraries via `binaryTarget`, which I have working just fine (with a framework built by an xcodeproj) - the distribution part isn't the issue, it's the actual building.

I should state that when the library package is referenced as a dependency in source form, all the symbols are perfectly accessible and everything works as expected.

In summary, how do I compile a SPM library package to a framework? There is next to no documentation on this anywhere and I'm at a loss.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem (where my archive is completely empty) when I build using xcodebuild, was wondering if you managed to come up with a solution?

Comment: @Rajusa I adopted the script marcprux linked below (or a customised version of it) - works a treat. Seems that there's an bug where artefacts don't get copied into the built product but they are present in the intermediates so can be copied in manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't yet any supported way to do it, according to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/741100, which came out of the (3-year-old) https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-build-swift-package-as-xcframework/41414. There's more information at https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655768.

This manual solution does seem to work for products declared as `.dynamic`, but requires some scripting, or else the creation of an Xcode project container.

Comment: The script you linked there is just the job. It seems that the missing elements of the framework are emitted by the build process, but not included in the final package. Given they're present in the build artefacts, you can just copy them in manually.